# PhpStorm Array Shapes nested arrays in array

Tags: php, arrays, phpstorm

I wanted to add array shapes to an array in PhpStorm `@var` tag in property, but I can't seem to get it done.

An array contains validating rules, where the key is the name of the attribute (string) and the value is the validating rules in the form of an array, where each rule is an array in which 1st element is a rule (an object of the `Ruleable` class) and the second element is a message when rule failed (string).

For example array could look like that:

```
$this->rules = [
    'FIELD' => [
        [$ruleable1, 'Field is empty'],
        [$ruleable2, 'Field is incorrect'],
        [$ruleable3, 'Some other error'],
    ],
    'OTHER_FILED' => [
        [$ruleable4, 'Field is empty'],
        [$ruleable5, 'Field is incorrect'],
    ]
];
```

where all `$ruleableX` variables are object of `Ruleable`

I've tried:

```
/**
 * Rules
 *
 * @var array<string, array<int, array{0: Ruleable, 1: string}>>
 */
protected array $rules = [];
```

but it doesn't work.

In that case:

```
public function validate()
{
    $a = $this->rules['FIELD'][0];
    $b = $a[0];

    foreach ($this->rules as $field => $rules) {
        foreach ($rules as $rule) {
            [$rule, $message] = $rule;

            if (!$this->checkRule($rule, $field)) {
                $this->addMessage($field, $message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`$b` should be interpreted by IDE as `Ruleable` and it is not (mixed),
also `[$rule, $message`] should be: `Ruleable` and `string` but both are mixed.

Any suggestion?  Is it possible at all?

I know that I could use `/** @var Ruleable $rule */`
but I wonder there is possible to do that by array shapes.

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2021/07/phpstorm-2021-2-release/#array_shapes_phpdoc_syntax_support

Comment: I've already been there. What's more, I was even here:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2022/02/phpstorm-2022-1-eap-3/

Comment: You can use inline PHPDoc to hint the type of $rule and $message inside the loop. This should help PhpStorm understand the types of $ruleable and $message within the loop.

Comment: @user580950 I know, but in that way that by only solution for loop, and when i call $this->rules in other place i will need to put it again.

Comment: You're correct that this solution only helps the IDE understand the types within the scope of the loop. If you need to reference $this->rules elsewhere in your code, PhpStorm might not infer the types correctly based on the property's PHPDoc alone.
Unfortunately, this is a limitation of PHPDoc and type inference in IDEs like PhpStorm. PHPDoc provides a way to document the types of complex structures like arrays, but it doesn't always guarantee that the IDE will correctly infer types in all contexts, especially when dealing with nested arrays or complex structures.